# Centering label and UITextField inside a TableView

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

New to xcode/swift, spending a couple of days now trying to fix this one.  Creating a universal app and having problems getting the constraint working programmatically.  I would like to programmatically add a label and a UITextField inside a TableView.  The label should always have a fixed width.  The text field should have variable width depending on the device.

Here is what is looks like now:

[image]

Here is an idea of how it should look:

[image]

The label should be a set width.  But the textfield should use the available screen.

Here is the code so far:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        // Setup Cell
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)

        // Make cell unselectable
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        // Process Each Row
        let row = indexPath.row
        switch row
        {
        case 0:
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "First Name:"
            label.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(40), height: CGFloat(30))
            cell.contentView.addSubview(label)

            var textField: UITextField = UITextField()

            textField.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(170), height: CGFloat(30))

            textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
            textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.magenta
            textField.text = "TEST"

            textField.textColor = UIColor.black
            textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            cell.contentView.addSubview(textField)

            let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.contentView, attribute: .leftMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: label, attribute: .leftMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
            let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.contentView, attribute: .rightMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textField, attribute: .rightMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

            cell.contentView.addConstraint(leadingConstraint)
            cell.contentView.addConstraint(trailingConstraint)

....
```

Please let me know if you need additional information before a downvote.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

**Answer by UpholderOfTruth:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        // Setup Cell
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)

        // Make cell unselectable
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        // Process Each Row
        let row = indexPath.row
        switch row
        {
        case 0:
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "First Name:"
            label.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(40), height: CGFloat(30))
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            cell.contentView.addSubview(label)

            var textField: UITextField = UITextField()

            textField.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(170), height: CGFloat(30))

            textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
            textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.magenta
            textField.text = "TEST"

            textField.textColor = UIColor.black
            textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            cell.contentView.addSubview(textField)

// Horizontal Constraints  
cell.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[label(==100)][textField]|", options: .init(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["label": label, "textField": textField]))

// Vertical Constraints
cell.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
cell.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
....
```

Comment: You should really use storyboard if you are new. The reason being: people learn visually. Also, you shouldn't combine constraints and frames into an object, just pick one.

Comment: ask yourself: Your label's leftMargin is aligned to the contentView of the cell. Good. But what about your label's rightMargin?! Similar issue for your textField. They both have some undefined constraints...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest go full auto layout and don't mix methods.  So first set both view to use auto layout via setting the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false.

Then either set the constraints visually like this:

```
cell.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[label(==100)][textField]|", options: .init(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["label": label, "textField": textField]))
```

or with individual constraints like this:

```
cell.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
cell.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 100))
cell.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textField, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
cell.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

Of course this just handles horiztonal positioning and sizing you need to do something about vertical positioning and sizing as well but you may be setting that up further down in your code.

**Edit**:

To centre vertically you can do this:

```
cell.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
cell.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

**Edit2**:

Combining into a single line:

```
cell.contentView.addConstraints([NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0), NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)])
```

**Edit3**:

```
cell.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-8-[label(==100)][textField]-8-|", options: .init(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["label": label, "textField": textField]))
```

Comment: Thanks UpholderOfTruth!  How would I center both the label and textfield vertically?

Comment: I have edited the answer to include constraints to centre vertically.

Comment: UpholderOfTruth awesome, that worked perfect! Marked as answer.  Just out of curiosity, is there a way to accomplish the entire task with a one-liner?  (Set both horizontal, vertical with one line of code) Thanks.

Comment: Instead of addConstraint you could use addConstraints which takes an array.  It can start to get harder to read though.  I will edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks UpholderOfTruth.  It works too awesome. :)  One last question if you dont mind, if I want to move away from the right and from the left margins the label/text about 8 points so they are not so close to the margins, what would be involved in doing that.  Thank you again.

Comment: You can adjust the constant settings to move controls about.

Comment: Thanks UpholderOfTruth.  Is the option to add 8 points (or pixels) available using the cell.addConstraints (first option above).  Tried changing 0 to 8 and received an error message.

Comment: Edited to give an example of what I think you want.

Comment: Amazing. :)  Thank you very much UpholderOfTruth, with this last example of adding the 8 points, I finally understand the concept!  It works a little like regular expressions.  Much appreciated helping me learn this.

Comment: No problem glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Change these properties:

```
    switch row
            {
            case 0:
            let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.contentView, attribute: .leftMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: label, attribute: .leftMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
                let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.contentView, attribute: .rightMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textField, attribute: .rightMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

                cell.contentView.addConstraint(leadingConstraint)
                cell.contentView.addConstraint(trailingConstraint)

                let label = UILabel()
                label.text = "First Name:"
                //here is the trick: play with x and width. It might also be cell.contentView.size().width
                label.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(35), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(cell.frame.width * 1/3), height: CGFloat(30))
                cell.contentView.addSubview(label)

                var textField = UITextField()

                textField.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(cell.frame.width * 2/3), height: CGFloat(30))

                textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
                textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.magenta
                textField.text = "TEST TEST TEST"

                textField.textColor = UIColor.black
                textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

                cell.contentView.addSubview(textField)
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, first had to move label definition to the top in your code, then tried it with just "textField.text = "TEST" and it shrunk again.  It didnt take up the whole space as I am looking for.  Appreciate your help.